# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 after framework consist in cocoapod as vendor framework

Tags: c++, ios, swift, frameworks, arm

I am facing this weird issue, in which if I include the x framework directly to the project then it compiles perfectly however if I put that Framework inside a Cocoapod library (as vendor-framework) with private repos and then make "pod install", the header files from that same Framework shows me below warning and error.

```
ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied 'Pods/MyLib/X.framework/X', framework linker option at Pods/MyLivi/MyLib/X.framework/X is not a dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_X", referenced from:
  type metadata accessor for __ObjC.X in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is it for cocoapod because if this lib had caused for **arm64** then normally including it in project would have created that issue too.

NB: when I tried to run in a armv7 devices, it shows shown error for symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 so it should be error with install of cocoapod or configuration.

Comment: Are you sure you're opening the xcworkspace file and not the xcproj file? The project file will not compile if you're using cocoapods to manage your dependancies.

Comment: Perhaps update your cocoapods version with sudo gem install cocoapods. I've had issues with these and they are a pain to track down. Make sure you're adding the pod to your target and your target defines the architectures that you're building for.

Comment: @Dare..yes, I am opening the xcworkspace...

Comment: @GregP..there should not be any architectural issue as I am using that same framework in other project directly and it is working perfectly and working for that arm64? so do you think there are issue for architectural issue?

Comment: Hi I don't know but what i did, select that particular framework "Link Binary with libraries", AddOther and add that from Pod source and it started working!!!

Comment: May @GregP..Pod is not configuring the files properly!!!

Comment: Hi @GregP.. my assumption was right. Pod file was not configuring the files properly. What I did, I added the Frameworks added to Pod as iOS vendor framework, directly from the pod and added the header search path for them and it started working... Actually Cocoapod is not configuring the iOS_vendor framework correctly and also I feel, its not importing the system frameworks correctly too.. Too bad work!!! Thanks for your concern.

Comment: I've had issues like this with the cocoapods beta versions. Glad you figured it out.